# Color the equations in flalign and align environments

Tags: equations, color, align, flalign

I have two sets of equations in two different environments. I want to color few equations in both. Is it possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
        L(1)&=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}\cdot 1 \;dt&\\[8pt]
        &=\left[\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}\right]_0^\infty&\\[8pt]
        &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[e^{-st}\right]_{0}^{\infty}&\\[8pt]
        &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[e^{-\infty}-e^{0}\right]&\\[8pt]
        &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[0-1\right]&\\[8pt]
        &=\frac{1}{s}&
    \end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
    L(1)&=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}\cdot 1 \;dt\\[8pt]
    &=\left[\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}\right]_0^\infty\\[8pt]
    &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[e^{-st}\right]_{0}^{\infty}\\[8pt]
    &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[e^{-\infty}-e^{0}\right]\\[8pt]
    &=\dfrac{-1}{s}\left[0-1\right]\\[8pt]
    &=\frac{1}{s}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=1cm`.

Comment: Which equations would you like to color? All of them? Just some of them? If it's the latter, which ones should be colored? Which color should be used?

Comment: what did you try?  you can start a cell with `\color{red}` and it will be red.

Comment: @Mico color all equations. How can we color separate equation with different colors

Comment: then put \color{red} before the environment and \color{black} after it

Comment: It's not working. Is it possible to give colors globally to all equations as well as different colors to different equations?

Comment: @Math-Man - A claim such as "it's not working" isn't actionable. Please be more specific. E.g., are you getting error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to color *all rows* in an `flalign*` environment red, then just insert `\color{red}` immediately before `\begin{flalign*}` and `\color{black}` (or whatever color is the default) immediately after `\end{flalign*`.

If you want to color just a few rows red, I suggest you use `\mathcolor{red}{...}` for the rows in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\addtolength{\jot}{8pt}% just for this example

\color{red}
\begin{align*}
L(1)&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}\cdot 1 \, dt \\
    &=\frac{1}{s}\,.
\end{align*}
\color{black}

\begin{align*}
L(1)&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}\cdot 1 \, dt \\
    &=\left[\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}\right]_0^\infty \\
    &\mathcolor{red}{%
      =\frac{-1}{s}\bigl[e^{-st}\bigr]_0^{\infty}} \\
    &=\frac{-1}{s}[e^{-\infty}-e^{0}] \\
    &\mathcolor{red}{=\frac{-1}{s}[0-1]} \\
    &=\frac{1}{s}\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Thanks everyone